# How to Pick property based if is substring of given string in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

My goal is to type `removeUrl` function:

```js
type MyType = {
  name: string;
  last_name: string;
  children_url: string;
  children2_url: string;
  children3_url: string;
  // ...
}

function removeUrls(target: MyType): MagicType {
  const result = {}
  for (const key in target) {
    if (!key.includes('_url')) {
      result[key] = target[key]
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

This may be a simple question but I'm new to typescript generics world and it's quite difficult to find any good google results to this problem :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible on typescript 4.0.

---

But on the unreleased 4.1 beta via [Template Literal Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types) you have some options!

If you're new to typescript this will look a bit strange:

```
type UrlKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends `${infer Prefix}_url` ? K : never
}[keyof T]

type RemoveUrls<T> = Omit<T, UrlKeys<T>>
```

The `UrlKeys` type iterates over an objects properties. For each key, if the key `K` has some `Prefix` followed by a `_url` at the end, then return that key name, else return `never`. The `[keyof T]` at the end gets a union of all the keys that were not assigned to never.

Then `RemoveUrls` simply takes a type and `Omit`s any keys that would be considered `_url`s.

You would use those types like this:

```
function removeUrls<T>(target: T): RemoveUrls<T> {
  const result: Partial<T> = {}
  
  for (const key in target) {
    if (!key.includes('_url')) {
      result[key] = target[key]
    }
  }

  return result as T;
}

const result = removeUrls({ a: 123, b_url: 'http://example.com' }) // type: { a: number }
```

Note that this function is now has the `T` generic parameter to accept any type. And the return value is the the same type, minus the url properties.

Also, when building an object one property at a time like this, you would need to type the in progress object as a `Partial` to make it okay that not all properties are present while being constructed. Then in the return statement, you can cast it back to a full `T` since you know you have processed all the properties.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201013#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgTgGwNIRAZwDwBUB8UC8UA3gLABQUUA2klAJYB2UA1qgPYBmUWAugFxRaEAB7AIDACZooAAwAkRRhwhwoABTgQOdYQF8A+gFdEMqAH5BUAQwgA3FeV1VWITtx7lyoSFABKEAFs2e3gETFwCKAB5ALpgbAAaWEQUdGwcHE8yDkMGAGNgOjYmTSCQxHCcAApgAEM4AHMIYAEsAEoBfzKIUMricko84rRgKE00QwQW9XrC2oR0yKJdAahVjjZVKqGGEZZUeiY6xua2-opKei4qgEIXADpGPIRDCQg0KoByI0RPtrPSBdLmN3pNgM5UDxIscmuCXB4gVAVhdkatNMBjCVQVMoLVpFgANyOLI7PbjMGRUrBHoVKpEXECACMACYAMxJABGPwQAk+AAtgMAwHwAPQijZse5DAKfJFnMVQbzQem1ayGAIclRIoA)